# How to remove a row in Excel based on cell value?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an Excel and I want delete some rows based on the particular cell value, but the Excel is very very huge it has got around 75000  rows. I tried writing a normal function to loop through the sheet, check for the cell value and delete the rows if matched, but it is taking very long time. I waited for 30 min and program was still running can some one suggest me how to achieve this.

Following is the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

        For i = Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(i, 4) = 7 Then
                    Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

I tested this code for small Excel file with 50 rows and it is working fine. But when I try on the excel I wanted to try it kept me waiting for 30 min and could not complete.

Comment: Show your existing code and maybe you'll get some suggestions for improving it. Questions with code are more interesting. Plus, you've tagged this with both "macros" and "vb.net", so it's not even clear what language you're using.

Comment: What column and what value are you using??

Comment: I have added the code that i am using. Please have a look at it.

Comment: It appears that if column D has the value 7, you want to delete the row.....is that correct??

Comment: Also are there any blank cells in column D??

Comment: @ Gary is you are rite. there is no blank cells in column D

Comment: If you turn off Screenupdating and set calculation to manual before starting the loop it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete rows in which column D has the value 7 and there are no blanks in column D, then run:

```
Sub Tachyon()
    Dim rD As Range
    Set rD = Intersect(Range("D:D"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    rD.Replace "7", ""
    rD.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

**EDIT1**:

**DO NOT USE THIS MACRO**

Testing indicates that not only does it remove rows containing 7 in column D, it also removes rows whose cells containing 77 or 777.  It also corrupts values like 17 or 71.  We need something better.

**EDIT2**

This version has the problem fixed:

```
Sub Tachyon2()
    Dim rD As Range
    Set rD = Intersect(Range("D:D"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    rD.Replace What:="7", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    rD.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: let me check, I will let u know soon.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this info. But I have only 4 different values i,e 2, 4, 7, 9. Let me try your code and see if it works.

Comment: Gary, as i noticed your code removes only the value in the cell it doesnot removes the entire row. but it was still taking time. Am i doing any thing wrong?

Comment: It removes entire rows for me.  Try it on a small sample of data.