# Remove all rows in a table that have a number within column c. Hence, keeping only the ones with blanks

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

Hi I need help writing a code that will delete all the rows with a number (it can be any number and vary in number of digits) in column 3 (or c). I just want to keep rows where column c is blank. Given the data is a table  know I need to use list objects but I cant seem to get it to work. I've been able to write a code to delete   all rows with blank cells but now want to modify the code to keep the blank cells.

The following code is for deleting blanks which i want to modify to keep them

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range
With Worksheets("Errors").ListObjects("Table2")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Intersect(.DataBodyRange, .ListColumns("Master List Row").Range).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Hey I tried that and it does nothing. All the rows are still there. I initially tried changing the xlcelltype to constants but that deleted the whole column for some reason. I just want to delete rows where column c has a number

Comment: [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/08/17/two-new-range-functions-union-and-subtract/) and [this](https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm) may prove useful

Comment: A simple way to do this is to filter `Column C` by blanks and then delete the visible cells that remain (I.E. rows that are not blank in your target column). How to this is well documented on this site -

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Dim rowsToDelete As Range
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        If rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rowsToDelete = cell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set rowsToDelete = Union(rowsToDelete, cell.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next
If Not rowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
    rowsToDelete.Delete
End If
```

Comment: @urdearboy Not necessary to use `EntireRow` from my tests. But you're right for the final test, thanks. :)

Comment: Hi I'm a little confused (sorry new to the whole vba thing). Its just that i get an error at " For Each cell In rng".

Answer (score 0):

I think answer on this similar question can give you a good idea on how to go with this.

[How to remove a row in Excel based on cell value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730276/how-to-remove-a-row-in-excel-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I know how to do a search for a particular number, but in this case it can be any number ( 1 - 20000) and i just want to keep blanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove rows fast, here's a trick: 1) add dummy column, 2) insert there a formula which detects whether there's a number or not in a cell, 3) filter dummy column by True and 4) delete rows:

```
Sub FFF()

    Dim iIndex%    
    Dim list As ListObject
    Dim dummyCol As ListColumn

    With Worksheets("Errors")
        Set list = .ListObjects("Table2")
        '// Index of dummy column
        iIndex = list.ListColumns("Master List Row").Index + 1
        '// Insert dummy column
        Set dummyCol = list.ListColumns.Add(iIndex)
        '// Insert formula to detect number in a cell
        dummyCol.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=ISNUMBER([@[Master List Row]])"
        '// Filter dummy column
        list.Range.AutoFilter Field:=iIndex, Criteria1:=True
        On Error Resume Next
        '// Remove all filtered rows.
        '// Error handler deals with a case when
        '// no rows are filtered.
        dummyCol.DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        '// Remove filter
        list.AutoFilter.Range.AutoFilter
        '// Delete dummy column
        dummyCol.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, I just ended up filtering for blanks and deleting hidden rows as suggested above but i can see how this may work too. Thanks!